# read.csv error due to no column names (R)

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm trying to read a csv file in r.
The issue is that my file has no column names except for the first column

Using the read.csv() function gives me the 'Error in read.table : more columns than column names' error
So I used the read_csv() function from the readr library.
However this creates a df with just one column containing all the values.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Och8A.png)
What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: check 'header' and 'sep' parameter, probably  sep=',' and header=F ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the csv? Otherwise it's going to be tough to help you. It looks as though your data is stored in rows rather than columns, so this is not a standard delimuted format as far as I know. It will still be readable, but might require a bit of work to get it in the correct format. With only an image to work on, we won't be able to answer you other than by guessing.

Comment: Try `read.csv("file.csv", skip=1, header=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

First cut to read the data would be using `skip=1` (to not read in the first line, it appears to be descriptive only) and `header=FALSE`:

```r
quux <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE)
```

I find this format to be a bit awkward, we may want to reshape it a bit.

```r
quux <- setNames(data.frame(t(quux[,-1])), sub(":$", "", quux[[1]]))
quux
#      LON   LAT   MMM 1984-Nov-01 1974-Nov-05
# V2 151.0 -24.5 27.11       22.28       22.92
# V3 151.5 -24.0 27.46       22.47       22.83
# V4 152.0 -24.0 27.19       22.27       22.64
```

Many tools prefer to have the "month" column names as a single column, which is converting this data from "wide" format to "long". This is easily done with either `tidyr::pivot_longer` or `reshape2::melt`:

```r
dat <- reshape2::melt(quux, c("LON", "LAT", "MMM"), variable.name = "date")
dat
#     LON   LAT   MMM        date value
# 1 151.0 -24.5 27.11 1984-Nov-01 22.28
# 2 151.5 -24.0 27.46 1984-Nov-01 22.47
# 3 152.0 -24.0 27.19 1984-Nov-01 22.27
# 4 151.0 -24.5 27.11 1974-Nov-05 22.92
# 5 151.5 -24.0 27.46 1974-Nov-05 22.83
# 6 152.0 -24.0 27.19 1974-Nov-05 22.64

dat <- tidyr::pivot_longer(quux, -c(LON, LAT, MMM), names_to = "date")
```

From here, it might be nice to have the `date` column be a "proper" `Date`-object so that it "number-like" things can be done with it. For example, in its present form, sorting is incorrect since `Apr` will land before `Jan`; other number-like operations include finding ranges of dates (which can be done with strings, but not *these* strings) and adding/subtracting days (e.g., 7 days prior to a value).

```r
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, format = "%Y-%b-%d")
dat
#     LON   LAT   MMM       date value
# 1 151.0 -24.5 27.11 1984-11-01 22.28
# 2 151.5 -24.0 27.46 1984-11-01 22.47
# 3 152.0 -24.0 27.19 1984-11-01 22.27
# 4 151.0 -24.5 27.11 1974-11-05 22.92
# 5 151.5 -24.0 27.46 1974-11-05 22.83
# 6 152.0 -24.0 27.19 1974-11-05 22.64
```

---

Sample data:

```r
quux <- read.csv(skip = 1, header = FALSE, text = '
LON:,151.0,151.5,152.0
LAT:,-24.5,-24.0,-24.0
MMM:,27.11,27.46,27.19
1984-Nov-01,22.28,22.47,22.27
1974-Nov-05,22.92,22.83,22.64
')
```